# What does `p` option mean when starting Nginx

Tags: nginx

The documentation of Nginx starting options gives the following explanation for `-p` option:

```
-p prefix Set prefix path (default: /usr/local/nginx/). (version >= 0.7.53)
```

I don't really understand what this means. What could this be option used for? What is prefix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [installation/compiling](http://wiki.nginx.org/InstallOptions) guide:

> `--prefix=path` - defines a directory that will keep server files. This same directory will also be used for all relative paths set by configure (except for paths to libraries sources) and in the nginx.conf configuration file. It is set to the /usr/local/nginx directory by default.

The `-p` runtime option is used to override this default path set during the compilation.